# Symphony Route returns a 404 status code in the frontend

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, symphony-cms

I am working on a Symphony app and have tried to create a route using PHP. The problem is that even though the route is correctly defined in the backend, I get a 404 status code in the frontend when I try to retrieve the route.

**Backend:**

```
/**
* @Route("/fetch-stock-data")
*/

public function fetchStockDataAction(Request $request) {
    $this->disableViewAutoRender();

    session_start();

    $currentTime = time(); 
    $oneHour = 60 * 60; // 3600 seconds

    if (!isset($_SESSION['stock_data_timestamp']) || $currentTime - $_SESSION['stock_data_timestamp'] > $oneHour) {

        session_write_close();

        $apiKey = "KEY";
        $symbol = "AAPL";
        $queryURL = "https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_DAILY&symbol={$symbol}&outputsize=full&apikey={$apiKey}";

        $response = file_get_contents($queryURL);
        $data = json_decode($response, true);

        session_start();
        $_SESSION['stock_data'] = $data;
        $_SESSION['stock_data_timestamp'] = $currentTime;

    } else {
        $data = $_SESSION['stock_data'];
        session_write_close();
    }

    return new JsonResponse($data);
}
```

**And this is my front-end code:**

```
var apiUrl = `/fetch-stock-data`;

$.get(apiUrl, null, function (data) {
    globalStockData = data["Time Series (Daily)"];
    document.getElementById('cookieConsentMessage').style.display = "none";
    updateChart();
}).fail(function() {
    console.error("Error with response:");
});
```

Does anyone have any idea why I get the 404 error when I call the route?

Comment: Is there any route defined for the class under which this function `fetchStockDataAction` is present. Also, you can use `php bin/console debug:router` to list out the routes present in the application and verify the path is correct.

Comment: Yes, the route for the `fetchStockDataAction` method is defined using the @Route annotation, and it's set to /fetch-stock-data. If i use the `php bin/console debug:router` command, the route /fetch-stock-data is missing.

Comment: So how did you confirmed that **route is correctly defined in the backend**?

Comment: I used this official [documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/4.1/routing.html) from symphony.

Comment: So it that working with postman (or any other tool you are using)? If not, then surely, that is not configured correctly.

Comment: You got a new line between annotation and method start. Maybe that's an issue. You need to debug such kinda situation. Maybe you can start with adding a test route that does nothing but just print hello world.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you have to clear the php-cache.

```
php bin/console cache:clear
```

execute the command in prod folder

Comment: this works for me, thank you!